# Reduce and Group an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

This is my array of objects. I'm writing a custom script in google sheets to take in transaction data and break it down into a list of unique items where the ordered amounts are added up to create a more easily read purchasing history.

```
 products = [ 
      { id: 1,
        item: 'Beef',
        category: 'Meat',
        orderAmount: 5,
        caseSize: 1,
        unit: 'Lb',
        price: 50,
        supplier: 'Sysco' },
      { id: 2,
        item: 'Chicken',
        category: 'Meat',
        orderAmount: 10,
        caseSize: 2,
        unit: 'Grams',
        price: 100,
        supplier: 'Findlay' },
      { id: 3,
        item: 'Fish',
        category: 'Seafood',
        orderAmount: 15,
        caseSize: 3,
        unit: 'Lb',
        price: 40,
        supplier: 'Deodato' },
      { id: 1,    // This is an example duplicate entry
        item: 'Beef',
        category: undefined,
        orderAmount: 100,
        caseSize: 1,
        unit: 'Lb',
        price: 50,
        supplier: 'Sysco' } 
    ]
```

I'm a little stumped on how to break this down into another object like so, where duplicate items are removed but the orderAmounts for the duplicates are added up.

```
uniqueProducts = [ 
  { id: 1,
    item: 'Beef',
    category: 'Meat',
    orderAmount: 105, //this is the altered amount
    caseSize: 1,
    unit: 'Lb',
    price: 50,
    supplier: 'Sysco' },
  { id: 2,
    item: 'Chicken',
    category: 'Meat',
    orderAmount: 10,
    caseSize: 2,
    unit: 'Grams',
    price: 100,
    supplier: 'Findlay' },
  { id: 3,
    item: 'Fish',
    category: 'Seafood',
    orderAmount: 15,
    caseSize: 3,
    unit: 'Lb',
    price: 40,
    supplier: 'Deodato' }
]
```

I've been reading up on using the map and reduce functions but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement them using such big objects.

Comment: Hi, Please share what you have tried?

Comment: Why is the size of the object an issue? Can you do it on a smaller object with just the id and orderAmount?

Comment: What is the rule for merging when for the same property the values differ. Like in your example there is a difference in the `category` value of the objects that get merged...

Comment: Ah my apologies, the 4th object that is supposed to be the duplicate should have its category defined as "Meat" as well. If the ID's match up all other properties should be the same other than orderAmount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the elements to a `Map` and accumulate `orderAmount`:

```js
const products = [ { id: 1, item: 'Beef', category: 'Meat', orderAmount: 5, caseSize: 1, unit: 'Lb', price: 50, supplier: 'Sysco' }, { id: 2, item: 'Chicken', category: 'Meat', orderAmount: 10, caseSize: 2, unit: 'Grams', price: 100, supplier: 'Findlay' }, { id: 3, item: 'Fish', category: 'Seafood', orderAmount: 15, caseSize: 3, unit: 'Lb', price: 40, supplier: 'Deodato' }, { id: 1, item: 'Beef', category: undefined, orderAmount: 100, caseSize: 1, unit: 'Lb', price: 50, supplier: 'Sysco' } ]

const reducedProductsMap = products.reduce((map, p) => {
    const previousOrderAmount = map.get(p.id) !== undefined ? map.get(p.id).orderAmount : 0
    let newP = {...p}
    newP.orderAmount += previousOrderAmount
    map.set(newP.id, newP)

    return map
}, new Map());

console.log(Array.from(reducedProductsMap.values()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I love how condensed this is but I'm a little unfamiliar with some of the newer syntax. What exactly is the fourth line of your code snippet saying?

Comment: @Nice Turnip   ` e.orderAmount += map.get(e.id) !== undefined ? map.get(e.id).orderAmount :0` is getting the accumulated `orderAmount` of the product in the  map and adding it to the current element' `orderAmount`

Comment: Of course it could be not present in the map, so I add 0 in this case

Comment: I'm not sure if this is as intended, but this method mutates the original array.

Comment: @BenStephens Great catch! I fixed it now, thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to go back to the slightly more condensed nature of your previous version, possibly something like `let obj = map.get(e.id) ?? { ...e, orderAmount: 0 }; return map.set(e.id, Object.assign(obj, { orderAmount: obj.orderAmount + e.orderAmount }));` would work for the reduce function body. (Though possibly it's not as easy to read as the current version).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys this works great, definitely need to do some reading into the more condensed syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a generic `group` function that takes a `grouper` function to specify what makes an item a duplicate, and a `update` function to specify how to update the result when a duplicate is found -

```js
function group(input, grouper, update) {
  function reducer(res, item) {
    const uniq = grouper(item)
    return res.has(uniq)
      ? res.set(uniq, update(res.get(uniq), item))
      : res.set(uniq, item)
  }
  return Array.from(input.reduce(reducer, new Map).values())
}

const products = 
  [{id:1,item:'Beef',category:'Meat',orderAmount:5,caseSize:1,unit:'Lb',price:50,supplier:'Sysco'},{id:2,item:'Chicken',category:'Meat',orderAmount:10,caseSize:2,unit:'Grams',price:100,supplier:'Findlay'},{id:3,item:'Fish',category:'Seafood',orderAmount:15,caseSize:3,unit:'Lb',price:40,supplier:'Deodato'},{id:1,item:'Beef',category:undefined,orderAmount:100,caseSize:1,unit:'Lb',price:50,supplier:'Sysco'}]

const result =
  group
    ( products
    , item => item.id
    , (original, duplicate) =>
        ({ ...original, orderAmount: original.orderAmount + duplicate.orderAmount })
    )

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "item": "Beef",
    "category": "Meat",
    "orderAmount": 105,  // <- grouped
    "caseSize": 1,
    "unit": "Lb",
    "price": 50,
    "supplier": "Sysco"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "item": "Chicken",
    "category": "Meat",
    "orderAmount": 10,
    "caseSize": 2,
    "unit": "Grams",
    "price": 100,
    "supplier": "Findlay"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "item": "Fish",
    "category": "Seafood",
    "orderAmount": 15,
    "caseSize": 3,
    "unit": "Lb",
    "price": 40,
    "supplier": "Deodato"
  }
]
```

Above we see that `group` expects an Array as input and returns an Array as output. We could make it more useful if `group` accepts any [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and returns an iterable. Arrays are iterable so they will still work as expected, but other iterables also work -

```js
function group(input, grouper, update) {
  const res = new Map
  for (const item of input) {
    const uniq = grouper(item)
    res.set
      ( uniq
      , res.has(uniq)
          ? update(res.get(uniq), item)
          : item
      )
  }
  return res.values()
}

function* products () {
  yield {id:1,item:'Beef',category:'Meat',orderAmount:5,caseSize:1,unit:'Lb',price:50,supplier:'Sysco'}
  yield {id:2,item:'Chicken',category:'Meat',orderAmount:10,caseSize:2,unit:'Grams',price:100,supplier:'Findlay'}
  yield {id:3,item:'Fish',category:'Seafood',orderAmount:15,caseSize:3,unit:'Lb',price:40,supplier:'Deodato'}
  yield {id:1,item:'Beef',category:undefined,orderAmount:100,caseSize:1,unit:'Lb',price:50,supplier:'Sysco'}
}

const grouping =
  group
    ( products()
    , item => item.id
    , (original, duplicate) =>
        ({ ...original, orderAmount: original.orderAmount + duplicate.orderAmount })
    )

for (const item of grouping)
  console.log(item)
```

Note how the output is *not* wrapped in an Array -

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "item": "Beef",
  "category": "Meat",
  "orderAmount": 105,  // <- grouped
  "caseSize": 1,
  "unit": "Lb",
  "price": 50,
  "supplier": "Sysco"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "item": "Chicken",
  "category": "Meat",
  "orderAmount": 10,
  "caseSize": 2,
  "unit": "Grams",
  "price": 100,
  "supplier": "Findlay"
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "item": "Fish",
  "category": "Seafood",
  "orderAmount": 15,
  "caseSize": 3,
  "unit": "Lb",
  "price": 40,
  "supplier": "Deodato"
}
```

To get an array from any iterable, you can use the `Array.from` function -

```js
Array.from(grouping) // => [ ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are faster ways of doing this but a good starting point is to loop through your result for matches and append the item if it isn't in the list. Be sure to copy the object or else you'll change the original values.

```
uniqueProducts  = products.reduce((result,item)=> {

   var hit = 0;
   for(var idx=0; idx<result.length; idx++) {
      if (result[idx].id == item.id) {
          hit += 1;
          result[idx].orderAmount += item.orderAmount;
          idx = result.length;
      }
   }

   if (hit === 0) {
       result.push(Object.assign({},item));
   }
   return result;

},[]);
```